# Adding Gdx.app.exit() in AndroidLauncher

Tags: android, libgdx

In my LibGdx based android game, I planned to use the exit statement in AndroidLauncher class instead of the core LibGdx project. It works fine

```
Gdx.app.exit();
```

Question 
1. Will there be any difference if I use it in AndroidLauncher class instead of the LibGdx screen ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No matter from where you call `exit()` method on static reference of `Application` class.

It schedule an exit from the application.

On android, this will cause a call to pause() and dispose() some time in the future.

Keep in mind :

- It will not immediately finish your application.
- On iOS this should be avoided in production as it breaks Apples guidelines.